# How do I allow horizontal scrolling only for a row of images and show overflow, without horizontally scrolling the rest of the page?

Tags: html, css, scroll, overflow

I have a page with a body that's 960px wide and I have a row of images that I want to overflow out of the right side of the page, and allow for the display of the overflowed images and horizontally scrolling. I don't want the page as a whole to horizontally scroll, just that element.

It's relatively easy to get the horizontal scrolling to work, but I can't get the overflow images to show without also increasing the width of the entire page (and, hence, making the page horizontally scroll).

My CSS:

```
container{
  width:960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  }

.pic-container {
  white-space:nowrap; 
  overflow:scroll;
  }
```

My (simplified) HTML:

```
<body>
<container>
  <div class="pic-container">
    <div class="pic-row">
      <img src="1.jpg">
      <img src="2.jpg">
      <img src="3.jpg">
      <img src="4.jpg">
      <img src="5.jpg">
      <img src="6.jpg">
    </div>
  </div>
</container>
</body>
```

Here's a little diagram of what I'm looking for:

[image]

Comment: Are you willing to use javascript?  There are many many plugins out there that do this exact thing and it looks a little nicer without the scrollbar.

Comment: Here's one `Jquery` solution [that might do what you want](http://css-tricks.com/examples/MovingBoxes/#&slider1=1). [And here's another](http://jqueryfordesigners.com/demo/slider-gallery.html). But it sounds like you want the bounding box of the images to expand indefinitely, with a little scrollbar that slides the contents of it around...so neither of these will qualify, I think.

Comment: Totally willing to use javascript, but unfortunately jmeas, neither one of these are what I'm looking for.

Comment: Maybe I'll just have to query the window size and change the width of the pic-row div to match it. But that does seem pretty inefficient...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't figure out a way to do this with just html + css so I leaned on JQuery. This actually works perfectly, and it degrades nicely too — if there's no javascript, the images are still scrollable, they just don't bleed into the right margin (the '.pic-container' div by default has no width until the js adds it in).

```
// Update pic-container width
function picWidth() {
  win = $(document).width();
  width = String( Math.round(((win-960)/2) + 960) );

  $('.pic-container').css({'width' : width});
}
$(window).resize(picWidth);
picWidth();
```

Answer (score 3):

This might do what you're looking for ([see on JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/q4H9N/1/)):

```
<section>
  <div class="pic-container">
    <div class="pic-row">
      <img src="1.jpg">
      <img src="2.jpg">
      <img src="3.jpg">
      <img src="4.jpg">
      <img src="5.jpg">
      <img src="6.jpg">
    </div>
  </div>
</section>​
```

CSS:

```
body {
   overflow: hidden;
}
section {
  /* The width of your document, I suppose */
  width:600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  white-space:nowrap; 
  overflow: scroll;
}
.pic-container {
 /* As large as it needs to be */
  width: 1500px;
}​
```

What we do is hide the overflow of the `body`, which prevents the horizontal scrollbars, even if the page isn't wide enough to show everything. Then you make it show the scrollbars on the container `div`, with a set width (presumably, the width of your document) and make the content within that `div` as wide as you want.

Another implementation, which just sets the width of the `section` instead of the `body`, [can be viewed here](http://jsfiddle.net/Fds4J/).

Comment: Close, but your solution only gets me as far as what I already had.

That is, the overflow images are still not visible outside width of the container. I want the overflow images to be visible without messing with the width of the page.

Does that make any sense?

Comment: hmmm...maybe. Do you want scrolling? If you make the overflow images visible outside the width of the container, then this seems incompatible with having a scrollbar to let you see them all.

Comment: Or is it that you're looking for the position of the images, which are all always visible, to scroll left and right?

Comment: Second one. It's essentially a preview of what's going to come into the viewport... kind of. I wish I could find a good example online somewhere; I know I've seen it before. Using jquery is also no problem, if need be.

Comment: fun fact, this only worked for me when i removed the float:left on my images and displayed them as inline-block.