# Change slider for horizontal scroll?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i've done a horizontal picture gallery from the here: [How do I allow horizontal scrolling only for a row of images and show overflow, without horizontally scrolling the rest of the page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13146895/how-do-i-allow-horizontal-scrolling-only-for-a-row-of-images-and-show-overflow)

and i was wondering if there is anyway to change the slider at the bottom to something like a nano slider? Something like this:
[image]

I'd really appreciate some help

Comment: Can you post what you've got so far?

Comment: He has -> see the link

Answer (score 0):

Use `overflow-x: auto;` on your container (`section` in your example)

```
<section>
  <div class="pic-container">
    <div class="pic-row">
      <img src="1.jpg">
      <img src="2.jpg">
      <img src="3.jpg">
      <img src="4.jpg">
      <img src="5.jpg">
      <img src="6.jpg">
    </div>
  </div>
</section>​
```

CSS:

```
body {
   overflow: hidden;
}
section {
  /* The width of your document, I suppose */
  width:600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  white-space:nowrap; 
  overflow-x: auto;
}
.pic-container {
 /* As large as it needs to be */
  width: 1500px;
}​
```

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correctly, you want to change the styling for the scroll bar. If I'm correct, that isn't difficult. you should use Webkit Scrollbars for this. [Here's a pretty good article on it.](http://almaer.com/blog/creating-custom-scrollbars-with-css-how-css-isnt-great-for-every-task)

you would probably want something like this:

```css
::-webkit-scrollbar-track:horizontal {
  height: 3px;
  background: gray;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar:horozontal {
  background: white;
}
```

I'm not completely sure about it, thought. It's been a while since I've needed to style scroll bars.

note: since this is webkit it won't work in firefox (or maybe explorer, not sure) as far as I know, the only way to do this would be with javascript.

Comment: Hey Ethan, yes that's correct that's what i want. Hmm, any idea how to go about this with javascript (also i tried putting your code in my css and it doesn't have any effect T_T)

Comment: @quainte I'm not sure about using JS, I usually use CSS for all my styles. 

I haven't done much research regarding the topic, but I believe there is a [jQuery extension](http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/) that might work for you. If you try it our, I'd be interested in knowing how it works.

If you want to take another shot at it with CSS [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14150577/24874) is a really good answer to a question regarding scrollbar styling, it talks about cross-browser styling, too.